# How can I save the state of UISwitches on a TableViewController when navigating through different view controllers/table view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My checklist application has different sections where the main screen (UIViewController) with several buttons leading to various food items (Vegetables, Fruits, etc.). The buttons lead to a TableViewController page, where you can add items via "+" button that modally presents an "Add Item" view controller.

After adding items to the list, it puts the name of the item and a `UISwitch` at the far right. This switch represents the check part of the checklist. However, regardless of what state you leave it on, when you navigate between different subsections (like going from Vegetables List -> Home -> Fruits List -> Home -> Back to Vegetables List) and come back to the original list, all the switches are off.

I have an idea of what I have to do: `UserDefaults`. My idea is to store the state of the switch when the state is changed and then in the `viewDidLoad` function iterate through all visible elements and set the state of the switches to their saved states. However, I'm not sure where to start with this idea.

[Snapshot of a portion of my storyboard that depicts the design for my list area and my add items area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF2T9.png)

The list `TableViewController` is linked to a class called `MEListViewController`. Problem here is when I try to make an outlet in the ViewController class, it says that

> I'm not allowed to put Outlets on repeating objects.

So, How can I save the state of Switches and keep them in their user-selected state even when you navigate through different screens?

Currently switches can be toggled while looking at a list. Leave the list and come back to it and the switches are reverted to the default "OFF" state.

Comment: Just use an appropriate data model and save the switch states in the model

Comment: You need to persist your data somehow; I would suggest CoreData is more appropriate for your task than UserDefaults

Comment: @S Banerjee's: Have you tested my below solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your this problem

> "it says that I'm not allowed to put Outlets on repeating objects."

You need have a custom `UITableViewCell` class and then you can have `UISwitch` outlet there.

> Then to save a `UISwitch` state for further use

You can store only the selected cell index as state in `UserDefault` and check the same against the current index in `cellForRowAt` tableView method. 
If it is found then your last state is `ON` otherwise default one is `OFF`.

This code snippet will work as you expect:

> Custom `UITableViewCell` class

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var switchObj: UISwitch!
  @IBOutlet weak var textValue: UILabel!

  @IBAction func toggleState(_ sender: Any) {
    var loadValues: [Int: Bool]!
    if let values = Memory.getStatesFromMemory() {
      loadValues = values
    } else {
      loadValues = [Int: Bool]()
    }
    loadValues[switchObj.tag] = switchObj.isOn
    Memory.saveSwitchStatesToMemory(savedStates: loadValues)
  }
}
```

> `UIViewController` class

```
class CustomTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  var savedStates: [Int: Bool]!

  override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let values = Memory.getStatesFromMemory() {
      savedStates = values
    } else {
      savedStates = [Int: Bool]()
    }
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as? CustomCell
    cell?.switchObj.isOn = savedStates[indexPath.row] == nil ? false : savedStates[indexPath.row]!
    cell?.switchObj.tag = indexPath.row
    cell?.textValue.text = "Switch stored state >>"
    return cell!
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return 80
  }
}
```

> Custom class to use for save/retrieve values from memory

```
class Memory {

  static func getStatesFromMemory() -> [Int: Bool]? {
    if let switchValues = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SwitchStates") as? Data {
      let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: switchValues) as! [Int: Bool]
      return decodedTeams
    }
    return nil
  }

  static func saveSwitchStatesToMemory(savedStates: [Int: Bool]) {
    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: savedStates)
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "SwitchStates")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
  }
}
```

Comment: This almost works perfectly! When I turn off a switch (after turning it on), however, and leave the table view controller and then come back, they go back to their initial state of being on. I will try and figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I figure out the problem. Please replace this line (cell?.switchObj.isOn =  savedStates[indexPath.row] == nil ? false : true) with (cell?.switchObj.isOn =  savedStates[indexPath.row] == nil ? false : savedStates[indexPath.row]!) this in cellForRowAt method of UITableView. I also updated the answer!!

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Follow up question: I have multiple table view controllers that are identical except for the name (see an example here: https://imgur.com/Z8i9Idr). Although I have set the class for the prototype cells to CustomCell, how can I link the switches in all of the tableviewcontrollers to the switchObj? Is there a fast way or do I have to create several CustomCell classes, one for each tableviewcontroller?

Comment: @SBanerjee You don't need to create several classes here, just assign a CustomCell class to Cell and attach outlet of UISwitch to switchObj. Remember you can attach multiple outlet to object from multiple classes, it will get called as per invocation.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple implementation you could have an array of `Item` objects (below). When you toggle a switch, figure out which cell's switch was toggled, then update the `isOn` state in the corresponding `Item`.

When you dequeue a cell before displaying it, make sure to update the `UISwitch`'s state based on the value of the corresponding `Item`.

Here's a basic item class that can get you started.

```swift
class Item {
    var isOn: Bool
}
```